# Mysql query for finding 10 close marks of class

Tags: mysql

I want nearest 10 marks for particular student. For example John has marks 73 then i have to find 10 student with marks greater than 73 in ascending order nearest to John. My Table structure is (id,name,marks).

Comment: What statements have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name, marks
FROM table1
WHERE marks > (SELECT marks FROM table1 WHERE name = 'John')
ORDER BY marks
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You should use a 1-1 ID comparison instead of [name = 'John'].

Comment: @Ben: Of course you should, but that's not what he asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select s.id, s.name, s.marks
From students sj
Join students s On ( s.marks > sj.marks )
Where sj.name = 'John'
Order By s.marks
Limit 10
```

`sj` will be student `John` (assuming that you have only one John), and `s` contains all records with marks greater than John's.

The `Limit` limits the output to ten rows.

Comment: @Mark: Not sure why I thought that would work (not really using MySQL), but since I can't try it right now I removed it. Thanks for the comment, and (+1) for your answer, which is correct too.

Comment: The first value is an offset (zero = no offset). LIMIT 1,10 would cause the first row to be skipped. I don't think that's needed here. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: @Mark Byers: Thanks again, had already read documentation myself :)